# Jquery-steps library and GoToStep function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-steps

I came across function in `jquery.steps.js` library :

```
/**
 * Routes to a specific step by a given index.
 *
 * @static
 * @private
 * @method goToStep
 * @param wizard {Object} The jQuery wizard object
 * @param options {Object} Settings of the current wizard
 * @param state {Object} The state container of the current wizard
 * @param index {Integer} The position (zero-based) to route to
 * @return {Boolean} Indicates whether the action succeeded or failed
 **/
function goToStep(wizard, options, state, index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= state.stepCount)
    {
        throwError(_indexOutOfRangeErrorMessage);
    }

    if (options.forceMoveForward && index < state.currentIndex)
    {
        return;
    }

    var oldIndex = state.currentIndex;
    if (wizard.triggerHandler("stepChanging", [state.currentIndex, index]))
    {
        // Save new state
        state.currentIndex = index;
        saveCurrentStateToCookie(wizard, options, state);

        // Change visualisation
        refreshStepNavigation(wizard, options, state, oldIndex);
        refreshPagination(wizard, options, state);
        loadAsyncContent(wizard, options, state);
        startTransitionEffect(wizard, options, state, index, oldIndex);

        wizard.triggerHandler("stepChanged", [index, oldIndex]);
    }
    else
    {
        wizard.find(".steps li").eq(oldIndex).addClass("error");
    }

    return true;
}
```

I would like to use this function so every time user submit a form on `step 3` in the wizzard he would not be redirected again to `step 1` but to stay at `step 3`.

Bellow is mine script:

```
          $("#wizard-2").steps({
                headerTag: "h3",
                bodyTag: "section",
                transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
                onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
                {
                    $("#form-2").validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
                    return $("#form-2").valid();
                },
                onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
                {
                    $("#form-2").validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
                    return $("#form-2").valid();
                },
                onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
                {
                    $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                    .attr('name','ssl')
                    .attr('value', 'true')
                    .appendTo('#form-2');
                    document.getElementById("form-2").submit();
                }
            });
            <? if ($_POST['submit'])
                   echo "$(\"wizard-2\").goToStep(this, ,3,0);"?>
```

But I believe my execution of this function is pretty bad cause it ain't work. Could anyone help me out with this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out it myself. Problem was pretty easy and it was about setting correctly attribute `startIndex` like:

```
<?
if (Env::value('generate'))
    echo "startIndex: \"2\",";
?>
```